# How to speed up Vue.js command line processes and optimize a webpack build

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I have a very simple tutorial project that I built which consists of no more than 100-200 lines of code.

When I build this project with webpack I end up with a bundle.js file which is being flagged as being above the recommended size of a bundle.js file. I find this unsettling because I know that my code is very small. How is it that with only using a few things like vuex, vue.js and a few node modules ending up with such an oversized bundle.js?

I understand that it packages everything up for us, but I find it hard to believe that with such a small project webpack would be unable to get it down to a much smaller size. I am concerned that this might have something to do with the sheer number of node modules I have in that project root directory.

So my question is this: does the webpack build depend at all on what node-modules are in my directory under the /node_modules/ folder? If not, then how have I already exceeded the recommended size for a bundle.js with my first ever vue project?

This brings me to another question which I have been very unsure of: Is it normal for vue to copy over almost my entire node_modules directory from my root user directory? When I watch tutorials, the "vue create My_App" command seems to finish executing in no more than 10-20 seconds, but when I run the command it can take minutes. When I was wondering what it could be I saw that it copied hundreds and hundreds of node_modules over... is that entirely necessary? Is there a configuration or setting I should have set or changed that I missed?

Thank you all for any insight you might be willing to offer, big or small.

```
    // webpack.config.js
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/'
  },
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },
      // this will apply to both plain `.js` files
      // AND `<script>` blocks in `.vue` files
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      // this will apply to both plain `.css` files
      // AND `<style>` blocks in `.vue` files
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    // make sure to include the plugin for the magic
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
  },
};
```

Comment: This may be better asked on the [Vue.js forums](https://forum.vuejs.org/), as it doesn't really belong on SO

Comment: You need to at minimum share your webpack configuration.

Comment: Obviously webpack builds depends on what node_modules you're using. What's actually *included* in the final build depends on a lot of things.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I have updated it with my webpack.config.js file.... thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @user1538301 I will also ask on the Vue.js forums, thank you!

Comment: I don't think this is specific to Vue or needs to be specifically sent to the Vue forums. This is an issue with webpack configuration.

Comment: @a_here_and_now if it is all config you have, then it is not optimized at all. Also, bundle size depends not only on libraries number in node_modules, but also on how you import dependencies to your project. For example, you can easily get 500kb of Vuetify, if you attach it without any settings, or get 550kb from moment.js (because it shipped with all 30 locales, which take near 300kb space), so there are a lot of interesting caveates in building a project

Comment: Btw your config mode is `development`, and webpack do not make tree-shaking in Dev mode by default

Comment: @bonusrk is there a resource you might be able to direct me to where they discuss this at length? a youtube video is ideal but simple documentation is okay too. That way I don't have to keep asking people more extensive questions.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I also asked a question about the "Vue create My_App" command line process, as I was wondering why it is copying something like near a thousand or more node_modules, it is basically cloning all of the nodemodules from my user profile regardless of whether i'll actually need them.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean specifically by "copying"? If you mean then when you execute `vue create my_app` that it installs all necessary node_modules needed for development, testing, and deployment, that isn't necessarily "copying". If you build the project and examine the `dist/` directory created by `@vue/cli`, you will see it has no node_modules as it's a client-side/browser project. It would be deployed without node_modules as a browser cannot use node_modules. `@vue/cli` needs many, many different node_modules during development, but they don't all get bundled on build.

Comment: 86k to be sharp ;). But again, not all o of them goes to build. https://webpack.js.org/ webpack docs

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky so I shouldn't be surprised that it takes a couple minutes to create a new project? Basically, this is normal behavior? I just recall tutorials where the teacher only seemed to wait 10-20 seconds, but then again they could have paused and just started when it finished.

Comment: IMO "20-30 seconds" is an arbitrary value that depends on a number of factors including internet speeds, machine performance, operating system and similar. It's probably going to take a different amount of time for each person. That being said, that's the cost, and potentially one time cost, of out-of-the-box get a production ready configuration and development environment. Sure, it would be quicker with a super basic project like yours, but you won't get the features a tool such as @vue/cli provides. How many times will you be executing `vue create` for a single project anyway?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky All very good points. I barely use vue create at all, I was just very concerned that I had something wrong from a configuration standpoint. I think the lesson is that for the create there's nothing wrong but for my build I need to look into the basics of how to slim it down for production so it can be sped up a good bit.

Comment: @bonusrk what about my config file would need to change if I want to build it for a production build as you are referring to? When I run build with the vue-cli-service it immediately logs in the terminal:   "Building for production..."

Comment: because it uses other config :trollface =) if you run `vue inspect > output.js --mode production` you will see it

Comment: The size of your project is directly determined by your dependencies. Probably the only relevant code you had to share was the contents of your `package.json`. Vue itself is quite small, especially when compared to its alternatives (i.e: Angular). Most likely the size is coming from your other dependencies.

Answer (score -3):

Use tools like https://nx.dev/
You can find video here https://youtu.be/mVKMse-gFBI